# At what speed does air drag becomes important?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, estimation

Imagine an object that wants to move at a speed $v$ trough a fluid.
I was thinking that when i ride a bike, there is generally a speed at which [air drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) becomes a problem, but if i ride slow i does not affect the movement that much, making me think that riding slow is more efficient in the long term.

What is the criteria used to determine if the drag from the fluid is important or not?

Comment: First you need to ask how much drag is important to you? Then you can figure out or measure the speed that produces that much drag. It can be a complicated calculation. The size and shape of the object matters. E.G. A falling man experiences some drag. A man falling with a parachute experiences more.

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/536074/37364) may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two graphs from [Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/rinard/aero/formulas.html). The first one shows Force and the second one shows power requirements vs different velocities.

You can see at roughly 12kmph rolling resistance is same as drag. After that drag starts to increase much faster (proportional to $v^2$)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> What is the criteria used to determine if the drag from the fluid is
> important or not?

Air drag generally varies as the square of the speed. So, clearly, it becomes very important the greater the speed.

Hope this helps.